# Postgres equivalent to MySQL's \G?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Does anyone know if Postgres has a way to display query results "prettily", like how MySQL does when ending a query with \G on the command line?  For instance, "select * from sometable\G" as opposed to "select * from sometable;"

Many thanks!

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know what the \G option does, but based on the documentation it looks like the psql \x option might do what you want.

It's a toggle, though, so you do it before you submit the query.

```
\x
select * from sometable;
```

Answer (score 39):

Actually, you **can** enable \G mysql style formatting on a per-query basis in psql by putting the following in ~/.psqlrc:

```
\set G '\\set QUIET 1\\x\\g\\x\\set QUIET 0'
```

You can then use :G at the end of a query in the psql client the same as you would \G at the end of a query in the mysql client:

```
pagila=# select * from foo limit 1;
 id | uniq | val |       val_ts        
----+------+-----+---------------------
  1 |    1 |   3 | 2007-07-03 00:00:00
(1 row)

Time: 11.481 ms
pagila=# select * from foo limit 1 :G
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------------
id     | 1
uniq   | 1
val    | 3
val_ts | 2007-07-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: My next question after \x was how to turn it off. You solution resolves it graciously!

Answer (score 31):

Since PostgreSQL 10, `psql` has `\gx` which is the exact equivalent of mysql's `\G`

```
select * from sometable \gx
```

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> \gx [ filename ]
>      \gx [ |command ]
>        \gx is equivalent to \g, but forces expanded output mode for this query.
>       See \x.

The sequence `\x\g\x` does the same, but only when `\x` (=expanded display) is off. Otherwise it does the opposite! By contrast `\gx` always displays with the expanded output independently of the current regime of `\x`.

Answer (score 24):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22407861/46027):

You can append `\x\g\x` to the query just as you would with MySQL's `\G`. For example:

```
select * from users \x\g\x
```

Note the lack of `;` in the above line, this is intentional.

This has the effect of enabling expanded display, running the expressed query, and disabling expanded display, all in one statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle psql into extended mode with \x before you run a command, but you can't do it on a command by command basis like you can in mysql.